# How to Calculate the Total size of file searched using Find command

Tags: rhel, find

First I have to search the files using FIND command that will show only the files for December 2012

Secondly I need to see the total size of files searched

I used this command

```
find /storage/backup/rman/ -mtime +90 -mtime -120 -exec ls -lrth {} \;
```

But it also gave me the files of November which I don't want

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 8.7K Dec  1 22:40 /storage/backup/rman/full_011212.log
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 3.3G Dec 11 22:34 /storage/backup/rman/BKPPROD_aknskgvb.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 34M Dec  1 22:40 /storage/backup/rman/ctrl_011223
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 1.3M Dec  1 22:33 /storage/backup/rman/BKPPROD_8lnrq765.F_bkp
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 8.0K Dec 20 22:45 /storage/backup/rman/full_201212.log
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 34M Dec  2 22:42 /storage/backup/rman/ctrl_021223
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 2.5G Dec 11 22:38 /storage/backup/rman/BKPPROD_ajnskgvb.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 34M Dec 13 22:46 /storage/backup/rman/ctrl_131223
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 8.0K Dec 17 22:44 /storage/backup/rman/full_171212.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 8.0K Dec 10 22:38 /storage/backup/rman/full_101212.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 8.0K Dec 13 22:46 /storage/backup/rman/full_131212.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 1.4K Nov 30 22:00 /storage/backup/rman/full_301112.log
-rw-r----- 1 oraprod dba 34M Dec  8 22:46 /storage/backup/rman/ctrl_081223
-rw-r--r-- 1 oraprod dba 9.2K Dec 12 22:43 /storage/backup/rman/full_121212.log
```

when I pass the `du -ch` at the end of command this is the result:

```
8.0K    ./.gnome/gnome-vfs
12K     ./.gnome
24K     ./lsat-0.9.7.1/changelog
920K    ./lsat-0.9.7.1
8.0K    ./.gconf/desktop/gnome/accessibility/keyboard
12K     ./.gconf/desktop/gnome/accessibility
8.0K    ./.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/host-mdfr-prod/0
12K     ./.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/host-mdfr-prod
16K     ./.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard
20K     ./.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals
36K     ./.gconf/desktop/gnome
40K     ./.gconf/desktop
8.0K    ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets/clock/prefs
12K     ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets/clock
8.0K    ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets/workspace_switcher/prefs
12K     ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets/workspace_switcher
8.0K    ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets/window_list/prefs
12K     ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets/window_list
40K     ./.gconf/apps/panel/applets
44K     ./.gconf/apps/panel
8.0K    ./.gconf/apps/puplet
56K     ./.gconf/apps
100K    ./.gconf
8.0K    ./.nautilus/metafiles
12K     ./.nautilus
4.0K    ./.eggcups
196K    ./.gstreamer-0.10
4.0K    ./.redhat/esc
8.0K    ./.redhat
8.0K    ./.gnome2/share/cursor-fonts
8.0K    ./.gnome2/share/fonts
20K     ./.gnome2/share
4.0K    ./.gnome2/keyrings
4.0K    ./.gnome2/accels
4.0K    ./.gnome2/nautilus-scripts
36K     ./.gnome2
12K     ./.metacity/sessions
16K     ./.metacity
4.0K    ./.Trash
4.0K    ./.gnome2_private
68K     ./.gconfd
4.0K    ./.mozilla/extensions
4.0K    ./.mozilla/plugins
12K     ./.mozilla
4.0K    ./Desktop
2.5M    .
2.5M    total
```

Comment: Not very elegant but: `find -type f -mtime +90 -mtime -120 -exec du -c {} + | grep -E '^[0-9]+\stotal$'` would print one or more totals which you can add together to the grand total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some versions of `find` (non-embedded Linux, Cygwin, OSX, FreeBSD) allow you to compare a file's modification time with a reference date with the `-newermt` operator.

```
find /storage/backup/rman -newermt '2012-12-01' ! -newermt '2013-01-01'
```

You can't use `-mtime` to tell whether a file was modified at a particular date, because this operator is relative to the time you run the `find` command. If your `find` doesn't have the `-newermt` operator, create reference files and use the `-newer` operator.

```
touch -t 201212010000 start
touch -t 201301010000 end
find /storage/backup/rman -newer start ! -newer end
```

To get the total size of the files, use `du -c` and keep only the last (“total”) line. You'll need to exclude directories, because when you pass a directory to `du`, it adds up the sizes of all the files under that directory.

```
find /storage/backup/rman -type f -newermt '2012-12-01' ! -newermt '2013-01-01' -exec du -c {} + | tail -n 1
```

If you have a large number of files, the length of the command line might be too large, so `find` will run `du` multiple times and the command above would only list the output from the last batch. In that case you'll need to add up the amounts from each run. Here's one way to do this.

```
find /storage/backup/rman -type f -newermt '2012-12-01' ! -newermt '2013-01-01' \
     -exec sh -c 'du "$@" | tail -n 1' _ {} + |
awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

---

Exercise: what's wrong with the following command? (I.e. in what unusual but possible situation will it report a wrong figure?)

```
find /storage/backup/rman -type f -newermt '2012-12-01' ! -newermt '2013-01-01' \
     -exec du {} + |
awk '$2 == "total" {total += $1} END {print total}'
```

Comment: Not secure to pass `{}` in the shell code ;)

Answer (score 2):

First retrieve the file size in bytes, then sum them up:

`sed 's/\s\+/+/g' <<<$(find /storage/backup/rman/ -mtime +90 -mtime -120 -exec stat -c "%s" {} \;) | bc`

**EDIT**

To see the files as well,

`du -chs $(find /storage/backup/rman/ -mtime +90 -mtime -120)`

Comment: warl0ck, it it possible to also see the files because it only shows the size in bytes and later I calculated the size which is 51GB.

Comment: @UmairMustafa provided an alternative way

Comment: Still it is going Nov Files...... Otherwise it is great

Comment: @UmairMustafa I don't get what you mean

Comment: Actually what i mean is I only want the files of Dec and not Nov. When we pass the -mtime +90 -mtime -120 for some reason it also returns the Nov Files along Dec files.

Comment: I'd guess 120 days ago was in November 2012?

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649/how-do-i-get-the-unix-find-command-to-print-out-the-file-size-with-the-file-name

```
find . -name '*.ear' -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

just the h extra from jer.drab.org's reply. saves time converting to MB mentally.

Related Resources

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079740/find-files-with-size-in-unix

Answer (score 0):

for your second request (sum up file sizes), I am using:

```bash
find /storage/backup/rman/ -mtime +90 -mtime -120 -printf '%s\n' \
 | awk '{total += $1} END {printf "%.17g\n", total}'
```

- `-printf '%s\n'` prints the size only (requires the GNU implementation of `find`)
- awk does the math
- `printf "%.17g\n"` avoids scientific notation

to verify that it works:

```bash
fallocate -l 1M ./1m.txt
fallocate -l 2M ./2m.txt
echo $(($(stat -c '%s' ./1m.txt) + $(stat -c '%s' ./2m.txt)))
3145728
find ~/ -name '?m.txt' -printf '%s\n' \
 | awk '{total += $1} END {printf "%.17g\n", total}'
3145728
```

Reference:

- [gawk gnu manual example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#More-Complex)
- [Inexact representation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Inexact-representation)

Comment: That %.17g and reference to *inexact representation* should not be needed here as those are integers. You end up actually losing precision.Try after `truncate -s15T {1..10000}` for instance.